# Insert records to database table via controller method

Tags: database, controllers

Can anyone tell me how to insert records to database table via controller method?

Comment: Are you trying access Models via Controllers or something else ?

Comment: Yes.. That only.. I want to insert record to database table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this way

**First way without model**

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$entity_id =1; 
$entity_type_id =4; 
$attribute_id = 92;
$value = 'red'; 
$store_id  =1;
$resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeAdapter   = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table        = $resource->getTableName('some_table_name');
$query        = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`entity_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`,`store_id`) VALUES ($entity_id, $entity_type_id, $attribute_id, $value, $store_id);";
$writeAdapter->query($query);
```

**Second way use model**

```
$data = array(
    'entity_id' => 1,
    'entity_type_id' => 4,
    'attribute_id' => 92,
    'value'    =>  'Red',
    'store_id' => 1         
);

$model = Mage::getModel('your_model_name'); //for eg. Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

try {
    $model->setData($data)
    ->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check default core controllers file where it done in many places.

For example if you check file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

and action `createPostAction()` you will get the idea how they are storing data for customer.

You can follow the same way for your custom table using your model

```
$model = Mage::getModel('modulename/modelname');
$model->setData($yourData);
$model->save();
```

You can set individual fields also

```
$model->setField($yourFieldValue);
```